# Send message to user on ConversationUpdate event in Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, events, botframework

In Bot Framework documentation there is a [good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events) where mentioned how to handle `ConversationUpdate` event which allows to initiate message to user when he connects:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
    bot.send(new builder.Message()
        .address(message.address)
        .text('Hello user, good to meet you!'));
    }
});
```

What if `function (message)` defined in other **.js** file module, like this:

```
var dialog = require("./rootdialog");
bot.on("conversationUpdate", dialog.ConversationUpdate);
```

How to send message in this case as `bot` variable is not accessible there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick which comes to my mind is implementing a universal function which return a function. Then, pass the bot to an universal function and return the required callback function as its result:

```
 function ConversationUpdate(bot)
 {
      return (message) => {
          if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
              bot.send(new builder.Message()
             .address(message.address)
             .text('Hello user, good to meet you!'));
          }
      }
 }
```

So, you can write what you want as the following:

```
var dialog = require("./rootdialog");
bot.on("conversationUpdate", dialog.ConversationUpdate(bot));
```